# Creating Unit test using Jasmine for a multi select Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have a multi-select textbox(over-writing the mousedown) which I have to test using jasmine. 
Here's my code for the textbox, jquery in an external.js and jasmine test-

```
<select multiple onclick=multiSelect() name="tagList"
id="tagListID" title="Tag List" size=3 class="form-control select">
<option> Java </option>
<option> PHP </option>
<option> MySQL </option>
<option> Maven </option>
```

external.js

```
function multiSelect(){
    $("#tagListID").mousedown(function(e){
    alert($(this).val());
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var select = this;
    var scroll = select .scrollTop;
    e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
    setTimeout(function(){select.scrollTop = scroll;}, 0);
    $(select ).focus();
}).mousemove(function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

jasminetestfile

```
describe(
    "multiSelect tests",
    function() {
        const tag1 = "Java";
        const tag2 = "PHP";
        const tag3 = "MySQL";
        beforeEach(function() {
            $('<select multiple onclick = multiSelect() name="tagList" 
id="tagListID" title="Tag List" size=3 class="form-control select"><option 
value="java" id="java">'+ tag1 +'</option id="php">'+ tag2 +'</option 
id="mysql">'+ tag3 +'</option></select>').appendTo('body');
         });

        it("select the tag on click", function(){
            var spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#java', 'click')
            $('#java').click();
            expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#java');
            var selectedOption=$("#java").val();
            expect(selectedOption).toEqual("Java");
});
});
```

So, what I want to test is when the option is clicked the selection is equal to Java. 
I don't know how to simulate the mousedown event in my test as it is being called inside the multiSelect function which is running on a click and not mousedown.